# WPF-Window between desktop and icons (Windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have used the brilliant article from CodeProject.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows
This project running fine for me on windows 8.1

The example using Forms. Now I'll change the Form
to WPF-Window (using Visualstudio 2015 with .net 4.5.2).

```
// The WPF-Window for infos behind the icon
public partial class InfoBehindIcon : Window
{
    public InfoBehindIcon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // in .xaml: the decoration switched off
    }
}

// The MainWindow - class
    ....
    private HInfoBehindIcon.InfoBehindIcon infoBehindIcon = new HInfoBehindIcon.InfoBehindIcon(); 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         ....
        iniDesktopHandlerWPF();

        ... in CodeProject example starting here the Form with
         //   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(InfoBIForm);
        ... how to start here the WPF-Window behind the Icon?

    }

    private void iniDesktopHandlerWPF()
    {
       ... Code from CodeProject example 
        if(dc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // here I change the Form to WPF-Window
            infoBehindIcon.Loaded += infoBehindIcon_EventWPF;
        }
    }

    private void infoBehindIcon_EventWPF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        infoBehindIcon.Topmost = false;
        InfoPanel.HW32.SetParent(new WindowInteropHelper(infoBehindIcon).Handle, workerw);
    }
```

The version using Forms running without problems.
When I am trying this with changes to WPF the second window is starting but 
it is not running between desktop and icons.
Is there a way to solve this?
Or it is better way to use furthermore the Form?
(sorry I am a newbee in C#)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was too simple and easy. I solved this

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         ....
        iniDesktopHandlerWPF();

        ... in CodeProject starting here the Form with
         //   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(InfoBIForm);
        ... how to start here the WPF-Window behind the Icon?

    }
```

with

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         ....
        iniDesktopHandlerWPF();

        ... in CodeProject starting here the Form with
         //   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(InfoBIForm);
        ... how to start here the WPF-Window behind the Icon?

        infoBehindIcon.Show();          
    }
```

Now it works fine for me. I did not see it...... ;)